# unable to view local server after installing django-sslify

Tags: python, django

This morning I started my Django development server and accessed it through `localhost:8000` and everything loaded as desired. Sometimes when I access the site through the terminal by clicking the address in the terminal: `Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/` and it works just as well.

I stopped the server and did `pip install django-sslify` to install [this](https://github.com/rdegges/django-sslify). I added the middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'sslify.middleware.SSLifyMiddleware',
    # ...
)
```

and added this line for Heroku:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

I ran the development server and attempted to access the site using both of the above links but the page wouldn't load. I panicked and ultimately removed all the lines I'd added and `pip uninstall django-sslify` and re-ran the server. I couldn't access the site on the above links still but I *could* access it through `0.0.0.0:8000`.

I then reinstalled django-sslify, added the code and re-ran the server trying to access it through `0.0.0.0:8000`. No dice.

Now, I've uninstalled it again and when I access it through `https://localhost:8000/` it gives me an SSL connection error and a message in the console:

```
code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('\x16\x03\x01\x00\x9d\x01\x00\x00\x99\x03\x01\xef\xb5\xae\xf6\xddUOY\x8d\x8a\xce\x9e!\x983\xbd\xfc4$\xb4')
You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
```

When I try access `http://localhost:8000/` it tells me the page is not available.

What happened?

Comment: OK, it works locally now. Any idea how to fix the `django-sslify` issue?

Comment: Or perhaps should I open another question?

Comment: I've got it sorted anyhow. Since your comment answered the actual title in the question, could you post it as an answer so I can put this awful ordeal behind me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your browser cached the HTTP 301/302 response that redirects your HTTP request to HTTPS. Clear browser cache or try another browser to test if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/rdegges/django-sslify#disabling-sslify) you should disable django-sslify for local development and unittests. Put in your `settings.py`:

```
if DEBUG:
    SSLIFY_DISABLE = True
```